# CSS Media Query, won't read the first code

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

So I code a CSS from Mobile Version first. After that I modify it to the larger screen.
When I do the larger screen, it's affect the smaller screen view, even I've set the value for smaller screen view.

CSS structure:

```
.m-dwSeotSecondSection__featureGroup {
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 4em 0 4em 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:800px){

        .m-dwSeotSecondSection__featureGroup {
    width: 22.5%; } 
}
```

The HTML structure:

```
<div class= "m-dwSeotSecondSection__fgContainer">
                <div class="m-dwSeotSecondSection__featureGroup -seo">
                    <div class="a-dwSeotSecondSection__icon -seo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="a-dwSeotHeading -heightdefined">
                    </div>
                    <p class="a-dwSeotDesc">
                    </p>
                </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: for screen less than 800px its taking 80% and above its taking 22.5%. Whats the problem here>?

Comment: it keeps taking 22.5% even if I resize the screen less than 800px.

Comment: Have u added 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS looks just fine, just check in your HTML head section if you have the following line:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want to default to the initial styles. If so, then maybe this will work:

```
.m-dwSeotSecondSection__featureGroup {
text-align: center;
width: 80%;
margin: 4em 0 4em 0;
border: 1px solid black
}

@media only screen and (min-width:800px) {
  .m-dwSeotSecondSection__featureGroup {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Media query will help you like

if you want to effect the given css in some specific screen then give media query like this

```
@media only screen (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 1200px){
    .class{
         property: value;
    }
}
```

now this css will only effect on greater then 767px width and less then 1200px width device. so it will not effect to other style

Answer (score 0):

It was answered by @Anuresh and @vuskovic09
I forgot to add